# rails jquery show hide with div and span ids not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I just have to ask ... its been almost a week and I could not resolve this error.

I have micropost feed and comments. All comments show within the correponding micropost.

I want to show/hide comments'  using jquery but all comments keep showing in all microposts.

I guess my problem is on coffee file, when click on "Mostrar" all microposts show its comments at once.

comments.coffee

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('span[id]').click ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('div[id]').fadeToggle()
    return
  return
```

comments.scss

```
div.ocultar { display: none; }
```

_micropost.html.erb

```
<% if micropost.comments.any? %>
  <span id="m-<%= micropost.id %>" ><%= link_to "Mostrar", "" %></span>
  <div id="m-<%= micropost.id %>" class="ocultar">
    <%= render micropost.comments, micropost: micropost %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def show
    @comment = Comment.find(comment_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the **4th line** of your **comments.coffee** file by this one:

```
$('div#' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeToggle()
```

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/uhskvxd8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Update in comments.coffee

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('span[id]').click ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('div#' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeToggle()
    return
  return
```